# Mock does not contain a definition for Setup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm new to Moq and having a problem to get it to work.

My code so far is as follows:

```
 private Mock _serviceMock;

 [SetUp]
 public void Setup()
 {
     _serviceMock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
 }
```

I have two methods in my interface but when I go to to use `_serviceMock.Setup` I get the error

> "Mock does not contain a definition for Setup".

I presume I'm missing a reference or something obvious here, but for once Google has failed me!

I have references to Moq and Nunit.Framework in my project and am using Moq version 4.10.0 and NUnit 3.11.0, all installed via Nuget.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The base `Mock` will not know anything about the generic type.

Use `Mock<IMyInterface>` instead.

```
private Mock<IMyInterface> _serviceMock;

[SetUp]
public void Setup() {
    _serviceMock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
}
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the framework

Comment: See, I knew it'd be something easy!  Thanks for you help!